# Subqueries in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to execute a query (that works perfectly in MySQL) with Redshift. There are no errors, but the result is just empty when it shouldn't compared to the result I get in MySQL. I have tried some other calls to the db in Redshift and everything is ok, the result is only empty when the query has subqueries.

Here is the query:

```
select T1.id, T2.provider_id as ID_2\
 from (select T0.identifier as id, T0.provider_id as ID_1\
 from schema.idtable T0 where T0.id IN " + str(ids) + ") T1\
 left join schema.providetable T2 on T1.ID_1 = T2.provider_id
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: please edit your question to make it MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . in this case include sample data and sample expected output.

Comment: That's not much info to go on but a common issue with migrating queries from other db platforms is not taking into account that Redshift treats all data as *case sensitive*. What could be happening is that the values in the join conditions have different casing and are therefore not matching in Redshift, where they may have done in MySQL.

Comment: There are [subquery limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html) in amazon-redshift but I don't see your query violating any of them. Sorry.